# Porque me salta este error

Tags: reactjs, consola, error404

Estoy utilizando react y sacando ideas de internet. copie un codigo EXACTAMENTE igual pero a mi me salta error y a la otra persona no. No entiendo que sucede. Me dice que la funcion agregarProducto, en realidad no es una funcion. Esto me ocurre cuando toco el boton de agregar al carrito.Adjunto las imágenes. Esta todo bien linkeado e importado
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
const ItemDetail = ({id, nombre, precio, img,desc, stock}) => {

const [agregarCantidad, setAgregarCantidad] = useState(0)

const {agregarProducto}//aca llamo a la funcion = useContext(carritoContexto)





const quantity = (cantidad) =>{
    setAgregarCantidad(cantidad)
    

    const item = {id, nombre, precio}
    agregarProducto(item, cantidad)//aca llamo a la funcion
}
}
```

Comment: El código y los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Además, pon el título lo que dice el error.

Comment: Pero la manera como importas esa función esta mal